# BLE Descriptor UUID

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, uuid, descriptor

I'm new in the world of BLE, I am currently able to connect to the BLE module and I can communicate with it/receive Data by pressing a Button.
Now I want to use the Descriptor, but I don't exactly know how to define the required UUID. I only discovered that it is 0x2902.
I want to use the following Code:

```
BluetoothGattCharacteristic init_gatt=mConnectedGatt.getService(STATE_REQUEST_SERVICE_UUID).getCharacteristic(STATE_CHAR_UUID);
            mConnectedGatt.setCharacteristicNotification(init_gatt,true);
            BluetoothGattDescriptor descriptor=characteristic.getDescriptor(STATE_CHAR_UUID);
            descriptor.setValue(BluetoothGattDescriptor.ENABLE_NOTIFICATION_VALUE);
            mConnectedGatt.writeDescriptor(descriptor);
```

Can anyone tell me how I can create the UUID which is necessary for this line?
`BluetoothGattDescriptor descriptor=characteristic.getDescriptor(STATE_CHAR_UUID);`

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for creating a random UUID, you can do that like this:

```
if(uniqueId == null) { 
    uniqueId = UUID.randomUUID().toString(); 
}
```

You can actually log the list of device supported using:

```
for (BluetoothGattDescriptor descriptor:characteristic.getDescriptors()){
    Log.e(TAG, "BluetoothGattDescriptor: "+descriptor.getUuid().toString());
}
```

Comment: I tried this Method but I got a Null ptr exception when using the get Descriptors() Method. I checked the services an characteristics with another BLE Scanner App and it shows me, that the specific service and chracteristic I am adressing have a Descriptor with UUID 0x2902.

Comment: So the NPE might ne because characteristics is null.

Comment: Update the code where you are setting the characteristic too.

Answer (score 0):

```
BluetoothGattCharacteristic init_gatt=mConnectedGatt.getService(STATE_REQUEST_SERVICE_UUID).getCharacteristic(STATE_CHAR_UUID);
            for (BluetoothGattDescriptor descriptor:characteristic.getDescriptors()){
                Log.e(TAG, "BluetoothGattDescriptor: "+descriptor.getUuid().toString());
            }
```

That's all I'm testing atm.
For the other Characteristic I'm Using, I got the hex Values which I have to write to the Characteristic by a collegue. In this case not